# Rails crashes on asset change

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

I have an inherited small rails website. I tried to do a change on a `css` file, only to find that rails gives me an error page (code 500) with the following error:

```
No such file or directory - /.../cache/assets/sprockets%2F1450c8f5d2b6e201d72fa175586bbd9720131025-15645-1c0s8zd.lock
```

I've tried:

1. Restarting rails server
2. Rebooting my computer
3. Clearing the assets cache
4. Clearing tmp
5. Turning down the server > rake assets:clean > rake tmp:clear > restarting server

The only solution that frees the error is deleting the changes I've done.

I honestly have no idea were to start looking, so if someone can give some pointers It'd be great.

Comment: Try to put config.assets.cache_store = :null_store  in environment

Comment: I guess you tried `rake assets:clean assets:precompile` also, right?

Comment: Pay attention on the strange path `/.../cache/assets` (three dots!). if you really have this message it can be source of the error.

Comment: `rake assets:precompile` gives me the same error I get in the page. 

@gotva That's path anonimization.

Answer (score 0):

Try to do in rails console

> Rails.cache.clear

or run in root directory

> rake tmp:clear

Comment: Tried that, doesn't work. Also tried to restart rails server after doing that and also doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Run this in your console:

```
bundle exec rake tmp:clear


bundle exec rake assets:clean


bundle exec rake assets:precompile
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Stupid mistake on my part: `rake assets:precompile` was failing because I didn't have write permissions to the tmp folder.